# Choose a photodiode with sensitivity matching a computer screen

Tags: photodiode, photosensor

I am showing a rectangle on a computer screen that needs to activate a digital (0/1) photodiode/photo detector that should only be activated when the white rectangle is shown on the screen.

I have already ordered the photo diode OPL550A that has a minimum photo sensibility of 0.250  mW/cm2 and it does not work. I need a stronger light source to make it work.

I want to order an OPL562 with sensitivity of  0.025 / 0.230 (minimum/maximum) which has Min that is 10 times less than my previous bad choice, but I am not sure that even this will be enough to match a white rectangle on my screen.

[OPL datsheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/414/OPL530_550_560-3241486.pdf)

I am not an electronics guy, but a programmer so forgive me for my lack of expertise.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? How are you using it? As long as not limited by noise, **any** sensitivity would do, you just need to increase the gain of your amplifier. But you don't tell us how you amplify at all! Well need to see a schematic.

Comment: Anton, the [OPL550A](https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Datasheet/OPL530-550-560.pdf) needs a pull-up resistor. Did you use one? And how are you determining "not work?"

Comment: When the rectangle appears on the screen there is no output voltage on the middle pin (output). I use 5V on the VCC. I do not amplify. The diode has 3 pins (vcc, output, ground). If I put a strong lamp (night lamp) towards the diode then it does produce 5V on the middle output pin. So for me it is a problem of sensibility. I was told that the diode has already a pull up resistor when someone checked the datasheet for me (but not sure now).

Comment: I am told that there is a an ampli + comparator + resistances and that it has everything it should. I added the datasheet as well in my question.